# Copy code and data types of namespace /FOO/ to second SAP system

Tags: abap, sap-basis

During the last weeks I developed some code with the namespace/prefix /FOO/. The namespace is official. It is registered at SAP.

If a second customer wants to use our code how one can transfer all code and data from this namespace from one sap system to a different sap system?

Under this namespace there are some data types and some abap code, some old SAP only (netweaver 7.4), no HANA.

This question is not about the usual transport (dev -> qual -> prod). This works.

Related: https://github.com/guettli/why-i-like-django-and-sap/blob/master/README.md#packaging

Comment: Just pack it into a transport and then import it in the target system. There are no checks on what you import, whether it is `Z`, `Y` or `/FOO/`. The only checks are done on software component versions which you can turn off by forcing it (if you are absolutely sure what you are doing). Make sure that all your dependencies for the `/FOO` coding are also in the target system. I assume you are familiar with the `STMS` transaction.

Comment: @guettli: do you mean the two SAP systems are not connected (so the usual STMS way does not work)?

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai yes (I think so, I don't know all features of STMS). Software developed for one customer should get used for a different customer.

Comment: OK, than this is a Basis issue: When the transport is released (I assume everything is one transport - at least this would be desirable), there will be two(1) files created. These two files have to be copied from the source SAP server, into the target SAP server. Basis should know which are the specific folders. This might also be useful: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Basis/Copy+Transport+Requests+to+local+file+system (1) I hope I remember correctly

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai thank you very much for your comment (Basis issue). Please write it as answer. Then I can up-vote it.

Comment: @guettli in the meantime this was answered by Jagger throughoutly

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could do that without the access to the operating and file system.

1. Release your workbench transport containing your code (either in `SE01` or `SE10`).
2. Each time you release a transport two files are written in `data` and `cofiles` directories which can be found in the `DIR_TRANS` directory (see `AL11`). Those files are named exactly like your transport with `R` and `K` prefix and the extension which is named after the SAP system name, let it be `XYZ` for the sake of this example.
3. Start the command line in SAP GUI with the report `RSBDCOS0` (transaction `SE38`).
4. Set the working directory to a directory of your choice and create there a folder named `transport` containing two subfolders `data` and `cofiles`.
5. Copy transport files into the `transport` directory in your working directory. On Windows system it could look like that.

   `copy %DIR_TRANS%\data\R<your_transport_number>.XYZ .\transport\data
   copy %DIR_TRANS%\cofiles\K<your_transport_number>.XYZ .\transport\cofiles`
6. Pack the contents of the `transport` directory in your working directory using SAP Archiver (`sapcar`) application. On a Windows system it could look like that.

   `cd transport
   sapcar -cvf XYZK<your_transport_number>.SAR data\R<your_transport_number>.XYZ cofiles\K<your_transport_number>.XYZ`
7. Download the file from the application server to your local client for example with `SE37` and function module `ARCHIVFILE_SERVER_TO_CLIENT`.
8. Upload the file to the target SAP application server with function module `ARCHIVFILE_CLIENT_TO_SERVER`.
9. Start operating system command line in the target server like you did in the point no. 3.
10. Unpack the `SAR` file.

    `sapcar -xvf XYZK<your_transport_number>.SAR
    copy cofiles\K<your_transport_number>.XYZ %DIR_TRANS%\cofiles
    copy data\R<your_transport_number>.XYZ %DIR_TRANS%\data`
11. Go to transaction `STMS` and refresh your transport import queue. The transport you wanted to import in the first place should now be visible in the queue.

`%DIR_TRANS%` has to be replaced with the directory you can see in the `AL11` of source and target system.

Comment: I think my usecase/question is common. Is there no official way to do this?

Comment: Of course there is. You can ask the people responsible for Basis to do it for you.

Comment: Is there no official (and public available) documentation for this process? I like doing things myself. Or at least I would like to be able to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try new SAP transport system that is promoted actively for new environments like S4HANA and is recommended as a replacement to CTS+, it is called [abapGit](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/21/abapgit-so-easy/).

Objects with namespaces `/FOOBAR/REPORT` are serialized with abapGit to `#foobar#report.prog.abap`

To move objects in customer namespace [you need](https://docs.abapgit.org/ref-namespaces.html) to create this namespace in the target system:

- Create namespace in SE03, namespace role = C, and add the repair license
- Open namespace for modifications in SE03
- Create namespaced package
- Change package original system to current in SE03 -> Change Object Directory Entries
- Clone/pull like normal

then pull them in a regular way via Git, they should appear in the customer namespace.

If all the namespaced objects are stored in the same package, the task is much simpler for you, 
[read here](https://docs.abapgit.org/guide-moving-package.html) about moving whole packages.